# How to connect stderr to stdin using pipes?

Tags: bash, pipe

The "|" pipe operator connects the **stdout** of one process to the stdin of another. Is there any way to create a pipe that connects the **stderr** of one process to the stdin of another keeping the stdout alive in my terminal?  Searching on the internet gave me no information at all...

Thank you in advance,
Michalis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use named pipes:

```
mkfifo /my/pipe
error-handler </my/pipe &
do-something 2>/my/pipe
```

This should keep stdin & stdout of "do-something" in your terminal und redirect stderr to /my/pipe, which is read by "error-handler".

(I hope this work, have no bash to test)

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy to *mix* stdouot and stderr, then you can first redirect stderr to stdout and then pipe that:

```
theprogram 2>&1 | otherprogram
```

If you don't want stdout, you can kill that one:

```
theprogram 2>&1 1> /dev/null | otherprogram
```

If you do want to store the original stdout as well, then you have to redirect it either to a file (in place of `/dev/null`), or to another file descriptor that you opened previously with `exec`. [Here are some details.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

(Unfortunately there is no direct "pipe this file descriptor" syntax like `2|`. That would have been handy.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but in fact I wand to keep alive the stdout and pass only stderr to the other process. Is there any way to such a thing?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print stdout to the console? You can easily store it in a file... to print it back to the console, I'm not sure, you may have to set up a couple of new file descriptors and redirect appropriately... check that link I posted.

Comment: Yes, of course. Here are the actual commands: `exec 3>&1;
porc1 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | proc2 3>&-;
exec 3>&-`

Answer (score 3):

You can get this effect with bash's process substitution feature:

```
somecommand 2> >(errorprocessor)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also swap the stdout & stderr streams, i. e. stdout becomes the new stderr and stderr becomes the new stdout).

```
# only the stdout stream gets upcased
ls -ld / xxx ~/.bashrc yyy 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]'

# block original stdout by closing fd 1
ls -ld / xxx ~/.bashrc yyy 2>&1 1>&- | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]'
```